# How do I select a particular item in a nodelist using the onmouseover function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of divs with the same class name and I want the background colour of one of the divs to change when I hover on it but when I hover on one, all the others change as well.

I tried turning the nodelist into an array then looping over the array but it still doesn't work.

This is what I have
please help me improve on it or show me another way to acheive what want

I would use the CSS `.card-content:hover:{display:flex}` but the original display is set to none so there is nothing to hover on

```js
function showContent() {
    const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content');  
    // for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    //     card[i].classList.toggle("show")
    // }  
    // // this.style.display= "flex";
    // for (const show of card) {
    //     console.log(show)
    // }
    // let cards = [card]
    // console.log(cards)
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = card.length; i--; arr.unshift(card[i]));
    // console.log(arr)
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        const show = arr[j];
        show.style.display= "flex";
    }
}
```

```css
.project.container{
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2vw 5vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.project .project_card {
    width: calc(50% - 2vw);
    margin: 1vw 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: violet;
}
.project .project_card.card1{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/dwyw.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card2{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/courselist.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card3{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/iqoption.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card4{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/slider.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card .card-content{
    background-color: #898987fa;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: flex;
}
.project .project_card .card-content a{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #242424b0,#000000c0);
    padding: 1vw 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
}
.project .project_card .card-content a:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000c0, #242424b0);
}
```

```html
<div class="project container">
        <div class="project_card card1" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card2" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card3" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card4" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card5" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card6" onmouseover="showContent()">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far, the best way to do this is with CSS's [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) to set the `display` of the `.card-content` element within the hovered `.project_card` element to `flex`:

```css
.project_card:hover .card-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

Live Example:

```css
.project.container{
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2vw 5vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.project .project_card {
    width: calc(50% - 2vw);
    margin: 1vw 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: violet;
}
.project .project_card.card1{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/dwyw.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card2{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/courselist.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card3{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/iqoption.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card.card4{
    background-image: url('../thumbs/slider.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.project .project_card .card-content{
    background-color: #898987fa;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: flex;
}
.project .project_card .card-content a{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #242424b0,#000000c0);
    padding: 1vw 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
}
.project .project_card .card-content a:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000c0, #242424b0);
}

.project_card:hover .card-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="project container">
        <div class="project_card card1">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card2">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card3">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card4">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card5">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_card card6">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3 class="name">{%NAME%}</h3>
                <p class="desc">{%DESC%}</p>
                <a href="" class="view">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But if you want to do it with JavaScript:

- Make sure your `showContent` function has access to the event (by passing it in if you use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, or by using modern event handling via `addEventListener`)
- Find any previous `.card-content` that has the class that makes it a flex (let's call it `flex`) and remove the class: `document.querySelector(".card-content.flex")?.classList.remove("flex");`
- Find the `.card-content` within the `.project_card` the event occurred on (`event.currentTarget.querySelector(".card-content")`)
- Add the class to it that gives it `display: flex`
- Use a `mouseout` or `mouseleave` that removes the class as well

As you can see, that's a lot more work than using CSS `:hover`.

Comment: wow 
well I didn't know you could do
.project_card:hover .card-content {
    display: flex;
}
in CSS so thanks for that. 
That's what I'll be using.
But I'm curious.
If I decided to use JS what would the code look like?

Comment: how would I make the appearance smooth? The transition property doesn't work